# How to Extract location and latlng from JSON produced by Mapquest geocoder api?

Tags: java, json, mapquest

I want to extract the location and its latlng from a JSON string returned by the [MapQuest Geocoder Api](https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/samples/geocoding/v1/address/) in java.

Comment: I use org.json as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the JSON response to an Object using Jakson and get the latlng from the object.

[JSON to Java Object](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-2-convert-java-object-to-from-json/) tutorial might help.